# how to put EXEC command in loop in TCL with windows platform

Tags: windows, for-loop, ffmpeg, tcl, exec

how to put EXEC command in loop in TCL with windows platform.

I need to run EXEC command continuously. but the problem after its first execution it stops.

my code is

```
proc a {} {
  set a 1
  for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    puts "I inside first loop: $i"
    exec ffmpeg -f dshow -benchmark -i "video=Integrated Webcam" \
            -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample_image.avi
  }
}
a
```

The above program should capture 10 video. but it captures only one video and comes out from the loop and stops the execution.

can any of my friend help me by providing me the answer with the required modification in code.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't create file `c:/test/sample_image.avi` once and overwrites it 9 times?

Comment: How many times do you see the "I inside first loop" message? 1 or 10?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Mathieu in comment you are writing all frames to the same file. To write 10 files use `i` to make the filenames unique. Also, tcl exec throws an error unless the `-ignorestderr` switch is passed, which may be the cause of early termination.

```
proc a {} {
  for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    puts "I inside first loop: $i"
    exec -ignorestderr ffmpeg -f dshow -benchmark -i "video=Integrated Webcam" \
            -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample_image${i}.avi
  }
}
a
```